# Remove new line from EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, enter

I have an `EditText` which is supposed to have multi-line while typing and should have an action done when enter is pressed, meaning the soft keyboard should disappear and the cursor made invisible... basically the `EditText` should lose "focus".

Now this is done and working, but the problem is that the "enter" key leaves a new line in the `EditText`.

I have tried to remove it by setting the entire text to `""`, but the `EditText` is blank with a new line.

I have tried to remove it by replacing `'\n'` with a `'s'` and setting the text back, but the text starts in a new line.

```
String cap = caption.getText().toString().replace('\n', 's').trim();
caption.setText(cap);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you set onClick listener corresponding to the EditText view ? Try, it should work.

Comment: why do you want to remove  spaces  at the time of editting ,I would suggest use trim function to remove extra spaces at the end

Comment: thanks for the reply guys. I need to have an edittext that does not show a new line upon hitting enter.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer but maybe it can help someone.

I recently had this problem and I solved it by implementing an `addTextChangedListener` to my `EditText`.

**Code:**

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
layout.addView(editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    boolean ignore = false; // This is used to prevent infinite recursion in the afterTextChanged method

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        if (ignore) return;

        ignore = true;

        String s = arg0.toString();
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            // The condition checks if the last typed char's ASCII value is equal to 10, which is the new line decimal value
            if (((int)(s.charAt(s.length()-1)) == 10)) {
                String newStr = s.substring(0, s.length()-1); // Removes the new line character from the string
                editText.setText(newStr);
                editText.setSelection(editText.length()); // Sets the text cursor to the end of the text
            }
        }

        ignore = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }
});
```

There might be better ways to get rid of the new line character, but this worked for me and seems simple enough.